# Multiple database populated dropdowns -- how to retrieve values via POST

Tags: php, mysql

I am very close to finishing a project I've been working on, thanks to the good folks at Stack Overflow. Yay! I've already looked at similar questions but they don't address it in the context of multiple dropdowns: **how do I submit a form with both selected values from a database in a dropdown as well as dropdowns without?** The dynamically generated values ('city', 'state') are not being posted. Part of the form:

```
<select name="city[]" id="city" multiple>
<?php
$query="SELECT City FROM Cities";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);
          while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo '<option value="'.$r['City'].'">'.$r['City'].'</option>'; }
          ?>
    </select>
```

The results from the database successfully show up. And the second page, where I assemble the query: **edit: updated**

```
            $where = array();
            $param = array();
               foreach($_POST as $key => $option) {
                if (
                    !empty($option)
                    and in_array($key, array('Role', 'issueInterest', 'targetPop','placement', 'targetIssues', 'City', 'state')))
                {
                    if (is_array($option)) {
                        foreach($option as $k => $optval) {
                            $where[] = "`".$key."` = ?";
                            $param[] = $optval;
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                            $where[] = "`".$key."` = ?";
                            $param[] = $option;
                    }
                }
            }

            $query_string = "SELECT * FROM dummy_table";

            if(!empty($where))
                $query_string .= " WHERE ".implode(' AND ',$where);

            $stmt = $db->prepare($query_string);
            $stmt->execute($param);
            echo '<pre>';
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            echo '<center><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="db-table">';
          echo '<thead><tr><th>Name:</th>
              <th>Email:</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>';
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
                echo "<tr><td>";
            echo $row['name'];
            echo "</td><td>";
              echo $row['email'] . '</td>';
            }
            echo '</pre>';
            ?>
```

If I choose someone from the database who is both a student (normal dropdown) and lives in New York(dynamic drop down), all students will be selected regardless of the city.

If there is a better way to do this than PHP and mySQLi, let me know.
Thank you!

Comment: You know that `City` and `city` are different keys?

Comment: @u_mulder Even with consistent capitalization it's not bringing anything up for me.

Comment: So start debugging - `print_r($_POST)`, `print_r($where)`

Comment: print_r($_POST) is printing: "Array([city] => Array ( [0] => New York City) )"

Comment: Okay, and what do you have in `$where` with this `$_POST`?

Comment: It's returning Array ( [0] => 'city' = ? )

Comment: Okay, that's what you need. Now check your `$query_string` and `$param`. Also show how you bind params to a statement.

Comment: I added my code which includes the parameter binding. The query string is just "SELECT * FROM dummy table" + the where array.

Comment: Please __always__ show exact value of a variable. What is there in `$query_string` __exactly__?

Comment: Also - are you sure that there're values in your table which satisfy your filter?

Comment: I did print_r($query_string) and this is the result, having selected from three dropdowns: "SELECT * FROM dummy_table WHERE `Role` = ? OR `targetIssues` = ? OR `city` = ?" print_r($stmt) returns PDOStatement Object
(
    [queryString] => SELECT * FROM dummy_table WHERE `Role` = ? OR `targetIssues` = ? OR `city` = ?
)

Comment: And, yes, in my test database I included everyone's city and ideally the query would be able to filter based on that.